# Adding numbers to array keys in print_r

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array with already keys and values like this:

```
Array
(
    [username] => someUser
    [email] => my@email.com
    [points] => -1118
    [country] => 213
    [played] => 1121
    [win] => 556
    [paid] => 1
)
```

But is it possible when doing a print_r with 'pre' around to add numbers like this?

```
Array
(
    [0][username] => someUser
    [1][email] => my@email.com
    [2][points] => -1118
    [3][country] => 213
    [4][played] => 1121
    [5][win] => 556
    [6][paid] => 1
)
```

This is just for the print_r function and should not be used for anything else!

Hoping for help and thanks in advance ;-)

Comment: what are going to accomplish ?

Comment: no. not with print_r. you'd have to hack the PHP source to get it to do that. You could roll your own `my_print_r`, or capture print_r's output and hack in the numbers. either way, not very fun.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not possible. [This](https://www.php.net/print_r) is what print_r does. You will have to make your own custom function to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Still using `print_r` :)

```
$a = ['username' => 'someUser', 'email' => 'my@email.com'];

echo preg_replace_callback('/\[(.+?)\]\s\=/', function($v) use (&$_) { return '[' . (++$_ - 1) . "]$v[0]"; }, print_r($a, 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this with `print_r()` alone, but you can grab the output of `print_r($array, true)`, and try to process it to get what you want. But this defeats the purpose of `print_r()` as it'd be easier to write own version of that function that iterates over your source array

Answer (score 0):

As veelen had pointed out, print_r is a tool that dumps array content to the screen in a human readable format. print_r does not allow the format to be changed.

You could knock something out like this:

```
function print_r_indexed($array) {
    $i = 0;
    foreach ( $array as $key => $val ) {
        echo "[$i][" . $key . "] => " . $val;
        $i++;
    }
}
```

then call the above function as below

```
$myArray = array ('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'email' => 'example@test.com' );
print_r_indexed($myArray);
```

However, this is a workaround. Probably shouldn't be doing things like these in the first place.